# Are "keyword research" and "keyword analysis" the same?

Tags: seo, keywords, research

Are "keyword research" and "keyword analysis" the same?

If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary says they are synonyms so I guess so.

I consider research would be looking for keywords while analysis would be studying the keyword already chosen.

Comment: I use the term "keyword prospecting"  for looking for keywords.   I use "keyword analysis" as studying a keyword already chosen.   I use "keyword research" broadly to encompass both of those activities.